# How does SuperCam measure the air?

Tags: mars, atmosphere, perseverance, supercam

[The NASA website](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/spacecraft/instruments/supercam/) mentions that the SuperCam onboard Perseverance can measure the air. How does it do this? Does it use [LIBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser-induced_breakdown_spectroscopy)? Is the SuperCam more apt at doing these measures than a regular camera?

Comment: I do remember reading somewhere that the laser will be used to measure something about the air, but I don't remember where or how; whether it's part of the optical system or something different like the microphone picking up the "snap@ snap! snap!" or some thing else entirely.